# ListView with Grid containing 2 objects for each column

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

In my application, I would like to display a ListView, with a vertical scroll. Inside the ListView, I would like to insert a Grid divided into two columns. Each column would like to have a list of objects in Binding, so 2 objects for each row. I thought of creating 2 ListView, with simultaneous scrolling, so that when I scroll on the left one, it also happens on the right one, as if it were a single. But the work is longer. Is there anything simpler than being able to use only a ListView with two objects for each row, one for each column?

This is my code XAML:

```
        <ListView x:Name="CategorySx" 
                  RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                  Type=Constant,
                  Constant=55}"
                  WidthRequest="130" HasUnevenRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding listSx}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>

                    <Grid RowSpacing="10">

                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Image x:Name="SX" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding ImageSx}"/>
                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  Text="{Binding TitoloSx}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

        <ListView x:Name="CategoryDx" 
                  RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                  Type=Constant,
                  Constant=200}"
                  WidthRequest="130" HasUnevenRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding listDx}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>

                        <Grid RowSpacing="10">

                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Image x:Name="SX" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding ImageDx}"/>
                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  Text="{Binding TitoloDx}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Yes, use collectionView https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/layout#vertical-grid

Comment: Does my solution work for you? If yes, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a collectionView with [Vertical grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/layout#vertical-grid) would achieve the result easily:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}"
                ItemsLayout="VerticalGrid, 2">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Padding="10">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="35" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="35" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Grid.RowSpan="2"
                       Source="{Binding ImageUrl}"
                       Aspect="AspectFill"
                       HeightRequest="60"
                       WidthRequest="60" />
                <Label Grid.Column="1"
                       Text="{Binding Name}"
                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                       LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" />
                <Label Grid.Row="1"
                       Grid.Column="1"
                       Text="{Binding Location}"
                       LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                       FontAttributes="Italic"
                       VerticalOptions="End" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```